# averaging columns on a very big matrix of data (approximately 150,000*80) in a normal runtime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am having problems with analyzing very big matrices.

I have 4 big matrices of numbers (between 0 to 1), each one of the matrices contains over 100,000 rows, with 70-80 columns.

I need to average each column and add them to lists according to the column title.

I tried to use the built in mean() method of pandas (the input is pandas dataframe), but the runtime is crazy (it takes numerous hours to calculate the mean of a **single** column) and I cannot afford that runtime.
Any suggestions on how can I do it with normal runtime?

I am adding my code here-

```
def filtering(data):
    healthy=[]
    nmibc_hg=[]
    nmibc_lg=[]
    mibc_hg=[]
    for column in data:
        if 'HEALTHY' in column:
            healthy.append(data[column].mean())

        elif 'NMIBC_HG' in column:
            nmibc_hg.append(data[column].mean())

        elif 'NMIBC_LG' in column:
            nmibc_lg.append(data[column].mean())
        

        elif 'MIBC_HG' in column and not 'NMIBC_HG' in column:
            mibc_hg.append(data[column].mean())
```

Comment: 150,000 rows shouldn't take that long. Can you show the output of `df.info()` for the relevant columns?

Comment: There must be something wrong in your processing, or an unusual type of data. A quick test on 1M rows takes 15ms `pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=1000000)).mean()`

Comment: you were right, I had a problem with the CSV file. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.mean()` and it will generate a mean for every numeric column in the dataframe df. The column name and summary results go into a pandas series. I tried it on a dataframe with 190,000 rows and 12 numeric columns and it only took 4 seconds. It should only take a few seconds on your dataset too.